# How to combine two or more associative arrays with keys as value of previous array element, creating a multilevel array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array which is in some kind of parent-child relation.

```
array: 4[▼
  "3669930.0010000787" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "0335573.541304.2225EMXNCDR"
  ],
  "0335573.541304.2225EMXNCDR" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0335573.441304.22294CHRR7D"
    1 => "0335573.441304.2234G9BPHBK"
  ],
  "0335573.441304.22294CHRR7D" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0335573.041304.222CZC7S32T"
    1 => "0335573.041304.222D7WP6BUP"
  ],
  "0335573.441304.2234G9BPHBK" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0335573.041304.222DJUVMSSC"
    1 => "0335573.041304.222FPGCBRXH"
  ]
]
```

So value for a key in this array, has another key with some other values and so on. For instance: "3669930.0010000787" has a value "0335573.541304.2225EMXNCDR", which is also a key with values "0335573.441304.22294CHRR7D" and "0335573.441304.2234G9BPHBK" and so on.

Now, what I need is that it an array is created that has key as "3669930.0010000787" and all other values in array as its value.

I was trying recursion method but got only these two values in array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "0335573.041304.222CZC7S32T"
  1 => "0335573.041304.222D7WP6BUP"
]
```

and here is my function:

$parents == the main array
$info = ["3669930.0010000787", "3669930.0010000788"];

```
private function _generate_aggregation_map( $info, $parents)
    {

        $aggr_map = [];

        //Serial Numbers, EPCs, gtins, quantity, packing_info -> to be changed


        for($x=0; $x<count($info); $x++)
        {
            echo($info[$x]);
            if( in_array($info[$x], array_keys($parents) ) )
            {
                foreach( $parents as $key => $val )
                {
                    if( $key === $info[$x] )
                    {
                        if( count($val) > 0 )
                        {
                            if( is_array($val) )
                            {
                                foreach( $val as $v )
                                {
                                    if( ! in_array($v, $aggr_map) )
                                    {
                                        array_push($aggr_map, $v);
                                        if( in_array( $v, array_keys($parents) ) )
                                            $this->_generate_aggregation_map([$v], $parents);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if( ! in_array($val, $aggr_map) )
                                {
                                    array_push($aggr_map, $val);
                                    $this->_generate_aggregation_map([$val], $parents);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $aggr_map;
    }
```

Actual result expected: Child values assigned to main parent key as a string.

```
["3669930.0010000787" => "0335573.541304.2225EMXNCDR , 0335573.441304.22294CHRR7D, 0335573.441304.2234G9BPHBK, 0335573.041304.222CZC7S32T, 0335573.041304.222D7WP6BUP, 0335573.041304.222DJUVMSSC, 0335573.041304.222FPGCBRXH"]
```

Thanks,

Comment: When calling `$this->_generate_aggregation_map`, it will return a new map, which you are not doing anything with - which is why you only end up with the top level.

Comment: Oh ok. So, any suggestion how I could solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: What do you pass to this function to start with, do you pass the same array as both parameters?

Comment: No `$parents ` is the main array at the top of question and `$info` is `["3669930.0010000787", "3669930.0010000788"]`

Comment: The title says you want to create a multilevel array; but the "expected output" seems to be a one dimensional array with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this in this way

```
$c['3669930.0010000787'] = traverse('3669930.0010000787',$a);

function traverse($parent, $arr, &$carry = []){
  $temp = $arr;
  if(isset($temp[$parent])){
    if(count($temp[$parent]) === 1){
        $carry[] = $temp[$parent][0];
        traverse($temp[$parent][0], $temp, $carry);
    }else{
        foreach($temp[$parent] as $v){
            $carry[] = $v;
            traverse($v, $temp, $carry);
        }
    }
  } 
  return $carry;
 }
 print_r($c);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/484D0

Answer (score 0):

As recursion can sometimes cause problems for even programmers to understand and follow, this just uses a simple loop and sets the values in the array at each point.  If the value has already been encountered, then it implode the previous entry and sets it in the new position - with the new key.

This processes the array in reverse so that when each item is encountered, the child will already have been added to the array.  This stops having to look through all of the data each time looking for the parent.

```
print_r(generateAggregationMap($data));

function generateAggregationMap ( $info )   {
    $aggr_map = [];
    $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($info), true);
    foreach ( $keys as $key )   {
       foreach ( $info[$key] as $entry )   {
           if ( isset($aggr_map[$entry]) )    {
               $aggr_map[$key][$entry] = $entry.",".implode(",", $aggr_map[$entry]);
               unset ($aggr_map[$entry]);
           }
           else    {
               $aggr_map[$key][] = $entry;
            }
        }

    }

    return [$key => implode(",", $aggr_map[$key])];
}
```

gives the output...

```
Array
(
    [3669930.0010000787] => 0335573.541304.2225EMXNCDR,0335573.441304.22294CHRR7D,0335573.041304.222CZC7S32T,0335573.041304.222D7WP6BUP,0335573.441304.2234G9BPHBK,0335573.041304.222DJUVMSSC,0335573.041304.222FPGCBRXH
)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is a great solution.